# how to replace multiple occurrences of a phrase mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to replace multiple occurrences of the same phrase in the same field.

Here is an example of the field 'imageUrl' contents:

> "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.test.com/s/files/1/0035/4671/0061/products/Screen_Shot_2019-12-13_at_12.47.01_pm_2000x.png?v=1576212956\n \n https://cdn.test.com/s/files/1/0035/4671/0061/products/Screen_Shot_2019-12-13_at_12.47.01_pm_2000x.png?v=1576212956\n \n \n"

My current formula:

```
  {
      $match: {
           imageUrl: { $regex: "_2000x" },
           brand: "Goat The Label"
      }
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          imageUrl: { $split: [ "$imageUrl", "_2000x" ] } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          imageUrl: { 
              $concat: [ 
                        { $arrayElemAt: [ "$imageUrl", 0 ] }, 
                        "_850x", 
                        { $arrayElemAt: [ "$imageUrl", 1 ] }
              ] 
          }
      }
 }]).forEach( doc => db.product.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { imageUrl: doc.imageUrl } } ) )
```

Converts the following to:

> "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.test.com/s/files/1/0035/4671/0061/products/Screen_Shot_2019-12-13_at_12.47.01_pm_850x.png?v=1576212956\n \n \n"```

However, im looking for the output to be:

> "imageUrl" : "https://cdn.test.com/s/files/1/0035/4671/0061/products/Screen_Shot_2019-12-13_at_12.47.01_pm_850x.png?v=1576212956\n \n https://cdn.test.com/s/files/1/0035/4671/0061/products/Screen_Shot_2019-12-13_at_12.47.01_pm_850x.png?v=1576212956\n \n \n"

Both urls still present and adapted to the `_850x` dimension.

**Note:** The field input may be more then one Url (could contain 2-7).

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) fits better for your use case:

### Pseudocode

```
value = url.split("_2000x")[0]
for (item: url.split("_2000x")[1:])
    value += "_850x" + item
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      imageUrl: {
        $regex: "_2000x"
      },
      brand: "Goat The Label"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      imageUrl: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $slice: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$imageUrl",
                  "_2000x"
                ]
              },
              1,
              {
                $size: {
                  $split: [
                    "$imageUrl",
                    "_2000x"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          initialValue: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$imageUrl",
                  "_2000x"
                ]
              },
              0
            ]
          },
          in: {
            $concat: [
              "$$value",
              "_850x",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Zcg1vmB5hr-)

**EDIT:** To execute via Bash shell:

***Windows:***

create temp.js file with:

```
db.collection.aggregate(...).forEach(...)
```

create temp.bat file with:

```
@echo off

path/to/mongo.exe --uri put_here_mongodb+srv temp.js
```

Now run: `temp.bat`

***Unix:***

create temp.js file with:

```
db.collection.aggregate(...).forEach(...)
```

create temp.bat file with:

```
#!/bin/bash

path/to/mongo --uri put_here_mongodb+srv temp.js
```

Give execution permissions: `chmod u+x temp.sh`
Now run: `./temp.sh`

Comment: any ideas how to load this from a bash command? im loading basically the whole command with some minor adjustments then committing with `.forEach( doc => db.product.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { imageUrl: doc.imageUrl } } ) )`. From the mongodb command line this works but trying to load via bash shell

Comment: @Kingswoop Sure. All you need to do: create ´*.js´ file with this aggregation. Then create new bash script (*.sh for unix, *.bat for windows) with content: `path/to/mongo[.exe] [-u username] [-p password] [host:port]/database path/to/*.js`

Comment: All good i fixed the issue. Needed to reference the db correctly from the command line using db.getSiblingDB.... Cheers thought!!!

Comment: @Kingswoop take a look my answer