# Replace string value with float value

Tags: mongodb

My data structure looks like this:

```
{
    customer: 10000001,
    metadata: {
        foo: '10.4',
        bar: 99
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is a mistake in my dataset as all values for `'metadata.foo'` have been stored as a string. There are 500 affected documents (the value is optional), so it is not possible to correct the values manually.

Is it possible to replace the string value with its float value if it is existing at all by terminal without executing some JavaScript code?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        'metadata.foo': { $exists: true }
    },
    {
        $toDecimal: <expression??>
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.update(
    {
        'metadata.foo': { $exists: true, $type:"string" }
    },
    [{
        $set:{"metadata.foo" : {$toDouble:"$metadata.foo"}}
    }],
    {multi:true}
)
```

I assume you have MongoDB v4.2

For MongoDB earlier v4.2, MongoDB doesn't allow override values by reading from itself.

**Walkaround #1:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{'metadata.foo': { $exists: true, $type:"string" }}
    },
    {
        $addFields:{"metadata.foo" : {$toDouble:"$metadata.foo"}}
    }
]).forEach(function(doc){
    db.collection.save(doc);    
})
```

**Walkaround #2:** Replace `,` to `.`:

```
db.collection.find({
    $match:{'metadata.foo': { $exists: true, $type:"string" }}
}).forEach(function(doc){
    doc.metadata.foo = parseFloat(doc.metadata.foo.replace(",","."));
    db.collection.save(doc);    
})
```

Comment: I'm using v4.0.

Comment: Only one problem: How can I handle string values like `'10,5'` which should be handled as `10.5`?

Comment: @user3142695 give me a sec

Comment: But your workaround can't be used directly in the terminal, right? So I think I will update to v4.2

Comment: @user3142695 Yes you can :). Tell me how are you going to execute update query?

Comment: Let's continue [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208668/discussion-between-valijon-and-user3142695)

Comment: Workaround #2: Should be `aggregate` instead of `find`, right?

Comment: @user3142695 not necessarily. Compare with JS vs [.aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60386331/3710490)